# Angular how to call child component function only if material data table is fully loaded?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have Father component and Child component. In father component i call data everytime params change, then child's component material table changes its data.

After each param change - data in table is different and I need to call a function from my parent component in that child component.

The problem : I can't call without timeOut , because everytime i call for data there is some MS delay till table component is fully loaded.

Example of what I have :

Parent comp :

```
@ViewChild(DataTableComponent) dataTableComponent: DataTableComponent;


getData(){
this.data.getData().subscribe( data => {

},

() => {
        if (this.dataTableComponent) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.dataTableComponent.selectAllHistoryItems(this.orderList.content);
          }, 500); //Else its undefined without timeOut
        }
})
}
```

Child component has :

```
public selectAllHistoryItems(items){
does something with new items in data table.
}
```

I want to make it work without timeOut, so parent component would call that function as soon as child component is ready.

Comment: You cannot use the "ngIf" on your component ? to wait until the orderList.content is no longer null for example ? You can also use data binding maybe, like use EventEmitter<>

Comment: Does angular material data table has some kind of subscription which tells when its fully loaded after data change ?

Comment: I never hear something like that, but yes it's a features that we are multiple to wait.